# Entity framework use between with strings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I realy stucked with my function. I have table and I'm using EF. Representation for this table in ORM is:

```
public partial class ProductAttributes
{
     public long Id { get; set; }
     public System.Guid AttrId { get; set; }
     public System.Guid ProdId { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }

     public virtual Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
     public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
}
```

This table contains FK to products and Attributes. Main responsibility of this table is to keep value for specified product and attribute. As you can see value represented as string.

Users on web site using sliders sets range for **values**. Now I should get all products from DB where **values** between users choice. Also a choose can be not range, just single value represented as a string. And here I got stuck.

Here function for selecting values from DB:

```
// Dictionaries  Guid - attributeID , string[] - values from slider
public IEnumerable<Products> GetFilteredProducts(Dictionary<Guid, string[]> searchParam)
{

    List<Products> list = new List<Products>();

    try {

     entityContext = new SiteDBEntities();
     IQueryable<Products> query = entityContext.Products;

     foreach (var item in searchParam)
     {
        //check do we have single value, it's mean that we whould search equals value
        if (item.Value.Length == 1)
         {
            var r = item.Value[0];
             query = query.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes
                                      .Any(y => y.AttrId == item.Key && y.Value.Equals(r)));
          }
         else
         {

           double a = Double.Parse(item.Value[0]); // min value
           double b = Double.Parse(item.Value[1]); // max value

 //AND HERE BECOMES BIG PROBLEMS

// this code will throw error becuase ToDouble cannot be converted to T-SQl
//               query = query.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes
//                                   .Any(y => y.AttrId == item.Key 
//                                   && Convert.ToDouble(y.Value) > a 
//                                   && Convert.ToDouble(y.Value) < b));

//this will return error cannot conver string to double
//                   query = query.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes
//                                       .Any(y => y.AttrId == item.Key 
//                                        && (double)y.Value > a 
//                                        && (double)y.Value < b));



 // this will return error 'cannot apply ">" to IEnumerable<double>'
//                         query = query.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes.
//                                             Any(y => y.AttrId == item.Key 
//                                             && y.Value.Cast<double>() > a 
 //                                            && y.Value.Cast<double>() < b));
 //            }

// this monster that I found on stackoverflow will return an error 'a lambda expression with body cannot be converted to expression tree'

//     query = query.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes.Any(p =>
//                            {

 //                               double val = 0;
//                                if (double.TryParse(p.Value, out val))
 //                               {
  //                                  return p.AttrId == item.Key &&
  //                                         val >= a &&
  //                                         val <= b;
 //                               }
 //                               else
  //                              {
  //                                  return false;
  //                              }
  //                          });
    }
}
catch(Exception){}
}
```

Maybe someone alredy faced with this issue and can help me? Here my slider:
[image]

Comment: If the value is a number, why do you store it as a string?

Comment: Because it can be string or double. It loades from external source and I can't be sure that this value is exactly number

Comment: @dantey89 maby it's better to convert it all to double?

Comment: @teovankot , I did it this way. I thought that it is not big deal to convert string to double... But I was wrong

Comment: instead of converting to Double, try converting your `a` and `b` to the type of `y.value`